# How to select merge changes in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I have a pending merge request and I am attempting to merge 2 branches via gitlab. I can see changes but there is no option for me to accept which change I would like to have:
[image]

Could someone clarify to me how do I accept the changes that I want when merging via gitlab?

Answer (score 0):

What you see is probably a diff view, not a merge view.

If there are conflicts, you should [see a "Resolve conflict" in the MR page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/conflicts.html).

[image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/img/merge_request_widget.png]

That should open a view with a "use this" button for you to chose one side or the other.

[image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/img/conflict_section.png]